# Total derivative with logarithm

Tags: derivatives, summation, logarithms

I have to take the derivative of the following equation:

$g(p) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_ix_i^{p}$

it says that the solution is

$g'(p) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_ix_i^{p}ln(x_i)$

but I do not understand where they god the $ln(x_i)$ from. Could you please explain?

Comment: LHS should be $g'(p)$, not $g'(x)$. Derivative of $x^{p}$ w.r.t. $p$ is $x^{p} \ln x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the $'$ in $g'(x,p)$ stands for differentiation with respect to $p$, and not $x$.

If $$g(x,p) = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i^p$$
then $$\frac{\partial g(x,p)}{\partial p}  = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i^p \log(x_i)$$
This is not the same as $\nabla_x\, g(x,p) = \left(\frac{\partial g(x,p)}{\partial x_1}, \ldots, \frac{\partial g(x,p)}{\partial x_n} \right)$.

---

*Answer to your edited question:* The derivative of $x_i^p$ with respect to $p$ is $x_i^p \log x_i$. Of course, we assume $x_i > 0$.